# Find the smallest missing number with Duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

This is an interview question, but I couldn't solve it in time, so posting it here:

Given a sorted array of n integers where each integer is in the range from 0 to `m-1` and `m > n`. Find the smallest number that is missing from the array.

Examples
Input: `{0, 1, 2, 6, 9}`, `n = 5`,`m = 10`
Output: 3

Input: `{4, 5, 10, 11}`, `n = 4`, `m = 12`
Output: 0

The code for this is as follows:

```
int findFirstMissing(int array[], int start, int end) {

    if(start  > end)
      return end + 1;

    if (start != array[start])
      return start;

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    if (array[mid] > mid)
      return findFirstMissing(array, start, mid);
    else
      return findFirstMissing(array, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Now, the question is that input array can have duplicates also:

`input = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]`

`output = 6`

How do I solve it efficiently? What kind of optimizations can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily proved that you have to this in O(n) time, as you can't distinguish without checking every single value two tables:

```
1,2,_3_,4,5,7
```

and

```
1,2,_2_,4,5,7
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in `O(N)` time and uses `O(1)` additional memory:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 5;
        int[] data = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5};

        int current = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            if (current == data[i]) {
                current++;
            }
        }

        if (current >= m) {
            System.out.println("All is here");
        } else {
            System.out.println(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `n` is actually ignored, I used `data.length` instead.

Comment: Can we have any better complexity? Any optimizations?

Comment: No, complexity cannot be lower than O(N), because you need to read all the numbers of the array at least once, this is O(N). You can do an optimization and stop iterating over an array if `current` is already equals to `m` - in that case we can say that everyone is here already.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Integer> input = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1));
    NavigableSet<Integer> sortedOriginal = new TreeSet<Integer>(input);

    NavigableSet<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=sortedOriginal.first();i<=sortedOriginal.last();i++){
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    for(Integer x : numbers){
        if(!sortedOriginal.contains(x)){
            System.out.println(x);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```